# Unable to run programs of SFM module in OpenCV

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, 3d-reconstruction, structure-from-motion

I am getting an error when I am trying to execute a sample code in SFM module. Initially SFM was not present in my contrib directory. So i downloaded the latest contrib and pasted the sfm folder in my contrib directory. I used the CMakeLists.txt that was present in the sfm module.
Then I tried to build it in my own directory with scene_reconstruction.cpp and the CMakeLists.txt which I took from the sfm module. Following is the error which I am getting

> > -- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
> >     -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
> >     -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
> >     -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
> >     -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
> >     -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
> >     -- Detecting C compile features
> >     -- Detecting C compile features - done
> >     -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
> >     -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
> >     -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
> >     -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
> >     -- Detecting CXX compile features
> >     -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
> >     -- Found installed version of Eigen: /usr/lib/cmake/eigen3
> >     -- Found required Ceres dependency: Eigen version 3.2.92 in /usr/include/eigen3
> >     -- Found required Ceres dependency: glog
> >     -- Performing Test GFLAGS_IN_GOOGLE_NAMESPACE
> >     -- Performing Test GFLAGS_IN_GOOGLE_NAMESPACE - Success
> >     -- Found required Ceres dependency: gflags
> >     -- Found Ceres version: 1.13.0 installed in: /usr/local with components: [LAPACK, SuiteSparse, SparseLinearAlgebraLibrary, CXSparse, SchurSpecializations, OpenMP]
> >     -- Checking SFM deps... TRUE
> >     -- Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen
> >     CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:35 (ocv_module_disable):
> >       Unknown CMake command "ocv_module_disable".
> >     CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
> >       No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as
> >     cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
> >     should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
> >       if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
> >       information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
> >     This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
> >     -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

PS: I went through all the required downloads of the libraries mentioned in the SFM documentation page before starting off.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to install the required dependencies like Eigen, Google log, Google Flags, and Ceres and download the corresponding opencv_contrib version for your opencv and build it with

```
-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules
```

and use the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( main )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( main main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( main ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Assuming you have main.cpp file, it should work, if you have correct installation.

For more information visit:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/sfm

and

https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/476